# Virtual Properties Not Updating in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to edit and update the database entry. Everything gets updated except one of my virtual property. What am I doing wrong?

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Plan plan, FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new _dbContext())
        {
            if (collection.AllKeys.Contains("PlanGroupID"))
            {
                var PlanGroupID = Int32.Parse(collection["PlanGroupID"]);
                var existingPlanGroup = db.PlanGroups.Find(PlanGroupID);
                plan.PlanGroup = existingPlanGroup;
                db.PlanGroups.Attach(existingPlanGroup);
            }

            Plan planContext = db.Plans.Find(plan.ID);
            db.Entry(planContext).CurrentValues.SetValues(plan);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Complete");
            }
    }

    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Model - Virtual Property

```
public virtual PlanGroups PlanGroup { get; set; }
```

Comment: What would you want to be updated? You didn't change anything in the plan group, you just added another plan to it (and therefore set the FK from plan to plan group to its PK). Also, attaching it again did not do anything, it should have been part of the context already after being retrieved by .Find().

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you attach to an existing plan group.

```
db.PlanGroups.Attach(existingPlanGroup);
```

When doing this, the state of the entity is unchanged.

Note that no changes will be made to the database if SaveChanges is called without doing any other manipulation of the attached entity. This is because the entity is in the Unchanged state. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx